# Allow only alphanumeric characters in a text input ( Prevent just numbers )

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I'm needing a validation function of a text input for "address" than only allows alphanumeric characters but doesn't allow only numbers.

If the input contains only numbers can't be submitted but if contains numbers and letters it's okay.

Thanks in advance!

Here's what i've got so far;

```
export const getRuleOnlyAlphanumeric = () => {
  return {
    pattern: {
      value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$/,
      message: "Address can't contain only numbers"
    }
    
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, the input field should have at least one alphabet, so I think the below solution could work for you. Just checking whether the string has an alphabet should suffice for the problem.

```js
const r = /[a-zA-Z]/i


const tests = [
'dGgs1s23', // true
'12fUgdf',  // true
'121232',   // false
'abchfe',   // true
'abd()*',   // true
'42232^5$'  // false
]

tests.forEach(test => console.log(r.test(test)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
const r = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/i


const tests = [

'dGgs1s23', // true
'12fUgdf' , // true
'121232'  , // false
'abchfe'   , // false
'abd()*'  , // false
'42232^5$'  // false
]



tests.forEach(test => console.log(r.test(test)))
```

Comment: I guess the 4th case should be true as per OP, since it restriction only on all numerics.

Comment: oh the thing is I tried to validate an address which usually has a number and a character and yes the question asked for the numeric case only but I am taking into account that the input is an address and that it should contain both that is why I wrote it like that